# regex for extracting date from string

Tags: regex

I have the following date string - `"2013-02-20T17:24:33Z"`

I want to write a regex to extract just the date part `"2013-02-20"`. How do I do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use capture group for this.

```
/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{1,2}).*/
```

Using `$1`, you can get your desired part.

Answer (score 7):

Well straightforward approach would be `\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d` but you can also use quantifiers to make it look nicer `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`.

Answer (score 3):

Just search for the first `T` and use substring. I assume you always get a well-formatted date string.

If the date string is not guaranteed to be valid, you can use any date related library to parse and validate the input (validation includes the calendar logic, which regex fails to achieve), and reformat the output.

No sample code, since you didn't mention the language.

Answer (score 1):

using substring

```
        string date = "2013-02-20T17:24:33Z";
        string h = date.Substring(0, 10);
```

Comment: not versatile at all