# PHP explode by date while keeping delimitter

Tags: php, arrays, explode

My string looks like this `05/21/2018 ghijkl 06/12/2018 mnopqrst`

I need to extract all the values after each date and include the date. I tried

```
explode('/2018', $string);
```

But that splits up the date and is also not future-proof. I'm thinking there must be a way to include the delimiter in the element. Perhaps there is also a regular expression I should be using to find the date?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex for extracting date from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129807/regex-for-extracting-date-from-string)

Comment: What is the expected output? You have three words but only two dates, it's unclear what you want

Comment: you're right. I edited the string. The text before the first date is irrelevant.

Comment: @FabianSchöner I don't think so. That is to just extract the date. I need the text after the date including the date

Comment: I have DV'ed because there is not a clear statement of the exact desired output from the sample input.  If this changes, ping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` and the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flags to keep the delimiter and remove the empty values from the resulting array.

You might use a pattern that matches a date format [`\b\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/b4zHxu/1) *(**Note** that it matches your date format in the example data and does not validate a date itself)*

For example:

```
$str = '05/21/2018 ghijkl 06/12/2018 mnopqrst';
$result = preg_split('@(\b\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\b)@', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/iLFCl)

To validate a date you could use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and perhaps specify your format using [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", '05/21/2018');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `current(explode('/', $string));`

Comment: That would explode the string on _all_ slashes, not just the ones that have the year, like `/2018`, which the OP clearly asks for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date is guaranteed to be formatted as you mentioned (if it's user input data, it's generally not safe to assume that), you could use a regular expression to find strings after a date:

Using a PHP regex split with the below expression:
`/([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{2,4})([a-zA-Z\s]+)/g`

Will break `05/21/2018 ghijkl 10/12/2017 mnopqrst` into an array with the different groups. Depending how you actually want the output data, you can capture the date and subsequent string in one match group.

Sample code:

```
$string = '05/21/2018 ghijkl 10/12/2017 mnopqrst';
preg_split('/([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{2,4})([a-zA-Z\s]+)/g', $string, $stringParts);

array (
    0 => '05/21/2018', 
    1 => 'ghijkl',
    2 => '10/12/2017',
    3 => 'mnopqrst'
);
```

https://regex101.com/r/gPXkDz/2

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$str = '05/21/2018 ghijkl 10/12/2017 mnopqrst';
$arr = explode(' ',$str);
$new = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i+=2){
  $new[] = ["date"=>$arr[$i],"value"=>$arr[$i+1]];
}
print_r($new);
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1028532)

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 05/21/2018
            [value] => ghijkl
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 10/12/2017
            [value] => mnopqrst
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using regular expressions. Here's an example code:

```
<?php

$string = '05/21/2018 ghijkl 06/12/2018 mnopqrst';
$matches = [];

if (preg_match_all('#(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})#i', $string, $matches) > 0) {
  echo "Found the following dates: \n";

  foreach ($matches[0] as $date) {
    printf("- %s\n", $date);
  }
}
```

This would result in the following output:

```
Found the following dates:
- 05/21/2018
- 06/12/2018
```